# Are there any restrictions on the binding between the queue and the exchange in rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

The comment in [amqp/channel.go](https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/1c71cc93ed716f9a6f4c2ae8955c25f9176d9f19/channel.go#L729) says:

> Non-Durable and Non-Auto-Deleted queues will remain declared as long as the
>   server is running regardless of how many consumers.  This lifetime is useful
>   for temporary topologies that may have long delays between consumer activity.
>   **These queues can only be bound to non-durable exchanges.**

but, the [rabbitmq-tutorials](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/8558268b23479d365cd6a2e3a40a4cdf21cbe8f6/go/receive_logs.go#L24) shows it is ok to bind a Non-Durable and Non-Auto-Deleted queue to Durable exchange.

Which is the correct one, are there any restrictions on the binding between the queue and the exchange?